# Accessing next element (not child) using css

Tags: html, css

I have following html structure

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input id="my_id">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-3-box" style="position:absolute; margin-left:340px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I using css target this second div

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-3-box" style="position:absolute; margin-left:340px;">
```

in order to change its margin-left value.

I tried with

```
#my_id + .col-sm-1 .col-3-box{
    margin-left:370px!important;
}
```

this doesnt work. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just remove space `#my_id + .col-sm-1.col-3-box`

Comment: As simple as @NenadVracar said

Comment: Nope. Notice that `#my_id` is inside `.col-sm-12`.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that this is not a valid html because you have a `</div>` that doesn't have open.

Comment: If you have the input inside a div, you can't target parents with CSS, so you can't target the input, then go back to the parent and then target the sibling. This must be made with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have markup:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input id="my_id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-3-box" style="position:absolute; margin-left:340px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

than this css:

```
.col-sm-12 + .col-sm-1.col-3-box{
    margin-left:370px!important;
}
```

---

If this markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input id="my_id">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-3-box" style="position:absolute; margin-left:340px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

than this css:

```
#my_id + .col-sm-1.col-3-box{
    margin-left:370px!important;
}
```

**Note**: there's no space between `.col-sm-1.col-3-box`.